# Algorithm for creating a circular path around a center mass?

Tags: ios, algorithm, trigonometry

I am attempting to *simply* make objects orbit around a center point, e.g.

[image: Orbiting Objects]

The green and blue objects represent objects which should keep their distance to the center point, while rotating, based on an angle which I pass into method.

I have attempted to create a function, in objective-c, but it doesn't work right without a static number. e.g. (It rotates around the center, but not from the true starting point or distance from the object.)

```
-(void) rotateGear: (UIImageView*) view heading:(int)heading
{
    // int distanceX = 160 - view.frame.origin.x;
    // int distanceY = 240 - view.frame.origin.y;

    float x = 160 - view.image.size.width / 2 + (50 * cos(heading * (M_PI / 180)));
    float y = 240 - view.image.size.height / 2 + (50 * sin(heading * (M_PI / 180)));
    view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, view.image.size.width, view.image.size.height);
}
```

My *magic numbers* 160, and 240 are the center of the canvas in which I'm drawing the images onto.  50 is a static number (and the problem), which allows the function to work partially correctly -- without maintaining the starting poisition of the object or correct distance.  I don't know what to put here unfortunately.

`heading` is a parameter that passes in a degree, from 0 to 359.  It is calculated by a timer and increments outside of this class.

Essentially what I would like to be able to drop any image onto my canvas, and based on the starting point of the image, it would rotate around the center of my circle.  This means, if I were to drop an image at Point `(10,10)`, the distance to the center of the circle would persist, using `(10,10)` as a starting point.  The object would rotate 360 degrees around the center, and reach it's original starting point.

The expected result would be to pass for instance `(10,10)` into the method, based off of zero degrees, and get back out, (`15,25`) (not real) at 5 degrees.

I know this is very simple (and this problem description is entirely overkill), but I'm going cross eyed trying to figure out where I'm hosing things up.  I don't care about what language examples you use, if any.  I'll be able to decipher your meanings.

**Failure Update**

I've gotten farther, but I still cannot get the right calculation.  My new code looks like the following:

`heading` is set to 1 degree.

```
-(void) rotateGear: (UIImageView*) view heading:(int)heading
{
    float y1 = view.frame.origin.y + (view.frame.size.height/2); // 152
    float x1 = view.frame.origin.x + (view.frame.size.width/2); // 140.5

    float radius = sqrtf(powf(160 - x1 ,2.0f) + powf(240 - y1, 2.0f)); // 90.13

    // I know that I need to calculate 90.13 pixels from my center, at 1 degree.      
    float x = 160 + radius * (cos(heading * (M_PI / 180.0f))); // 250.12
    float y = 240 + radius * (sin(heading * (M_PI / 180.0f))); // 241.57

    // The numbers are very skewed.
    view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, view.image.size.width, view.image.size.height);
}
```

I'm getting results that are no where close to where the point should be.  The problem is with the assignment of x and y.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: if you like, you can change the `bounds` of your view to have (0,0) at the center of rotation: `view.bounds = CGRectMake(-width/2, -height/2, width, height)`

Comment: when you say "nowhere close", what do you mean? flipped across the origin? (in many graphics libraries, (0, 0) is perversely at top-left.) off the screen? (check that something weird with int/float arithmetic isn't happening.) at the corner of your image instead of in the center? also: are those commented numbers what you expect, or what you've observed through a debugger? (if you haven't observed them through a debugger, you might try that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the distance of the point from the centre pretty easily:

> radius = sqrt((160 - x)^2 + (240 - y)^2)

where (x, y) is the initial position of the centre of your object. Then just replace 50 by the radius.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

---

You can then figure out the initial angle using trigonometry (tan = opposite / adjacent, so draw a right-angled triangle using the centre mass and the centre of your orbiting object to visualize this):

> angle = arctan((y - 240) / (x - 160))

if x > 160, or:

> angle = arctan((y - 240) / (x - 160)) + 180

if x < 160

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

---

Edit: bear in mind I don't actually know any Objective-C but this is basically what I think you should do (you should be able to translate this to correct Obj-C pretty easily, this is just for demonstration):

```
// Your object gets created here somewhere

float x1 = view.frame.origin.x + (view.frame.size.width/2); // 140.5
float y1 = view.frame.origin.y + (view.frame.size.height/2); // 152

float radius = sqrtf(powf(160 - x1 ,2.0f) + powf(240 - y1, 2.0f)); // 90.13

// Calculate the initial angle here, as per the first part of my answer
float initialAngle = atan((y1 - 240) / (x1 - 160)) * 180.0f / M_PI;
if(x1 < 160)
    initialAngle += 180;

// Calculate the adjustment we need to add to heading
int adjustment = (int)(initialAngle - heading);
```

So we only execute the code above once (when the object gets created). We need to remember `radius` and `adjustment` for later. Then we alter `rotateGear` to take an angle and a radius as inputs instead of `heading` (this is much more flexible anyway):

```
-(void) rotateGear: (UIImageView*) view radius:(float)radius angle:(int)angle
{
    float x = 160 + radius * (cos(angle * (M_PI / 180.0f)));
    float y = 240 + radius * (sin(angle * (M_PI / 180.0f)));

    // The numbers are very skewed.
    view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, view.image.size.width, view.image.size.height);
}
```

And each time we want to update the position we make a call like this:

```
[objectName rotateGear radius:radius angle:(adjustment + heading)];
```

Btw, once you manage to get this working, I'd strongly recommend converting all your angles so you're using radians all the way through, it makes it much neater/easier to follow!

Comment: @George Your radius seems correct given the values you've put in. The problem is that you haven't accounted for the angle at which your object starts (like in the 2nd half of my answer), you are still just using "heading". So instead of starting where you placed the object, it will jump to a starting angle of 1 degree and start orbiting from that position (is this what you see when you run the program?). Another problem is that you need to calculate the starting angle outside the rotateGear method, otherwise there doesn't seem to be any way to keep track of the starting angle.

Comment: @George I've added an edit with some (admittedly dodgy) Obj-C code, hopefully it makes it a bit clearer as to what I mean

Answer (score 0):

The formula for x and y coordinates of a point on a circle, based on radians, radius, and center point:

```
x = cos(angle) * radius + center_x
y = sin(angle) * radius + center_y
```

You can find the radius with [HappyPixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668358/algorithm-for-creating-a-circular-path-around-a-center-mass/6668410#6668410)'s formula.

Once you figure out the radius and the center point, you can simply vary the `angle` to get all the points on the circle that you'd want.

Comment: @George: you want to use the center _of the thing you're rotating around_, not the center of your canvas. i think they are `x1` and `y1` in your code? same thing when calculating the distance.

Comment: The center of my canvas is what I am rotating around

Comment: oh hmm. what is `heading` supposed to do, exactly? if you set it to `1` then it will snap the object to `1` degree away, using a ray going from the center of the canvas to the right as a basis. if you just keep calling the function, making `heading` go 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6..., it should rotate. but it will give the same result for each input. (giving it 1 repeatedly won't make it move). is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do `InitObject(x,y).` followed by `UpdateObject(angle)` where angle sweeps from 0 to 360. (*But use radians instead of degrees for the math)*
So you need to track the angle and radius for each object.:

```
InitObject(x,y)
    relative_x = x-center.x
    relative_y = y-center.y
    object.radius = sqrt((relative_x)^2, (relative_y)^2)
    object.initial_angle = atan(relative_y,relative_x);
```

And

```
UpdateObject(angle)
    newangle = (object.initial_angle + angle) % (2*PI )
    object.x = cos(newangle) * object.radius + center.x
    object.y = sin(newangle) * object.radius + center.y
```

Comment: your code looks right, except you need to keep track of the original angle (as in my example and in @HappyPixel's).  You need an `init` method which will give you `initial_angle` (+ radius if you don't want to keep re-calculating it).  Then you should be able to pass `initial_angle + heading` to your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
dx=dropx-centerx; //target-source
dy=-(dropy-centery); //minus = invert screen coords to cartesian coords
radius=sqrt(dy*dy+dx*dx); //faster if your compiler optimizer is bad

if dx=0 then dx=0.000001; //hackpatchfudgenudge*
angle=atan(dy/dx); //set this as start angle for the angle-incrementer
```

Then go with the code you have and you'll be fine. You seem to be calculating radius from current position each time though? This, like the angle, should only be done once, when the object is dropped, or else the radius might not be constant.

**instead of handling 3 special cases for dx=0, if you need < 1/100 degree precision for the start angle go with those instead, google Polar Arctan.*